# Unknown *emacs* process

Tags: debugging, process

I recently realized that every time I lunch emacs, after a minute, a strange buffer appear in buffers list that is linked to an emacs process, infact it also appear in system's process list:
[image]

When I try to close emacs `C-x C-c` in mini buffer appears a message that ask me if I'm sure to kill that buffer that has a running process.

That buffer contains only this line:

```
Lisp expression: Git variable `github.user' is unset.  Set to:
```

and I don't know how to interact with this buffer

If I kill the buffer without closing emacs, this message appear in mini buffer:

```
error in process sentinel: Selecting deleted buffer
```

Can you tell me a way to prevent the creation of this buffer/process?

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You should try to figure out what's going on firstly. Emacs has such behavior because of something you ask Emacs to do. By the way, "Git variable `github.user' is unset." is from ghub.el, and ghub.el is a github library, so maybe you asked Emacs to access github via some packages which requires ghub.el.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but I would guess: `async.el` judging by the name does some async stuff, so it may be running a separate Emacs process for this. You must have installed some package for interacting with GitHub that uses `async` library, but didn't configure how that package logs into GitHub or something similar.

Comment: I cleaned the .emacs.d folder and after I restored only known files and now the problem seems finally resolved. Thanks to all